# Passing data between components in Polymer 3

Tags: polymer-3.x, lit-element

I have 3 components: a `mainComponent`, a `SideMenu`, and `ContentArea` (both children of `mainComponent`). I want to make `ContentArea` see the changes of `popupOpen` value.

The function `togglePopup()` simply toggle the `popupOpen` boolean value.

In more details: I pass this function as property from `mainComponent` to `SideMenu`. The function changes `popupOpen` value, **but this change isn't reflected in `ContentArea`**.

**mainComponent**

```
class mainComponent extends LitElement {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.popupOpen = false
    }
    togglePopup() {
        console.log("togglePopup from main comp");
        this.popupOpen = !this.popupOpen
        this.requestUpdate();
    }

    render(){
        return html`
<div>
   <side-menu .togglePopup='${this.togglePopup}' popupOpen="${this.popupOpen}"></side-menu>
   <content-area popupOpen="${this.popupOpen}"></content-area>
</div>
`
    }
}
```

**SideMenu**

```
class SideMenu extends LitElement {
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
    static get properties(){
        return {
            popupOpen: Boolean
        }
    }
    render(){
        return html`
    <section id="side-menu">
            <a @click="${this.togglePopup}" >Add contact</a>
    </section>
`
    }

}
```

**ContentArea**

```
class ContentArea extends LitElement {
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
    static get properties(){
        return {
            popupOpen: Boolean
        }
    }
    render(){
        return html`
<section id="content-area">
<p>POPUP VALUE: ${this.popupOpen}</p>  <!-- this value doesn't change! -->  
</section>
`
    }

}
```

Comment: in maincomponent, you should declare popupopen as property

Comment: @alfredopacino  Except this, there are some syntax errors, all corrected are at below answer demo page.

Answer (score 2):

In order to fire `togglePopup` function properly, try:

```
<side-menu .togglePopup='${e=> this.togglePopup()}' .popupOpen="${this.popupOpen}"></side-menu>
```

instead :

```
<side-menu .togglePopup='${this.togglePopup}' .popupOpen="${this.popupOpen}"></side-menu>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/litelement-passing-data-between-components-in-polymer-3?file=index.js)